# Rails Production not appending relative_url_root to image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have app `foobar` that has a relative path. For example: `https://my_main_app.com/foobar`

In **config/environments/production.rb** I account for this with this setting:

```
config.relative_url_root = '/foobar'
```

My css, js, and image assets are in the assets directory:

```
+-- app
|  +-- assets
   |  +-- images
      |  +-- my_img.jpg
   |  +-- javascripts
      |  +-- application.js
   |  +-- stylesheets
      |  +-- application.css.scss
```

I run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and everything appears to compile ok. The css, javascript, and images all get put into the **public/assets** directory with an appended digest:

```
.
|  +-- app
|  +-- public
   |  +-- assets
      |  +-- application-<digest1234>.css.gz
      |  +-- application-<digest3456>.js.gz
      |  +-- my_img-<digest5678>.jpg
```

When I access the app:

- The css works great
- The js works great
- The image is 404 not found.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://my_main_app.com/assets/my_img-.jpg

I know what the issue is: the issue is that for the image: it is not appending the relative path of **foobar**. The correct path to the image is:

```
https://my_main_app.com/foobar/assets/my_img-<digest5678>.jpg
```

### Other detail:

I am loading the file like so. Within `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` I have this line:

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

Then in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` I have this line:

```
#header {
  background-image: image-url('my_img.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

So it appears that when the assets are compiled, it doesn't know about the relative path.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working but I did a number of things beforehand. It is unclear to me what exactly did the trick. Here are the things I know I did:

I completely cleared both my cookies and my cache.

I deleted the images from `public/assets`

I restarted the application server (passenger).

I recompiled the assets, but I made a few tiny adjustments to the command this time (used `rails` instead of `rake` and I specified the environment variable in the front).

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
```

It is unclear to me what exactly did the trick, but I am putting this here in case anyone runs into the same issue.